# Why showing request failed when post method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, session, axios

**Login Component**

```
class LoginUserComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      userName: "",
      password: "",
    };
    this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  changeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  login(event) {
    let userDet = {
      userName: this.state.userName,
      password: this.state.password,
    };
    const { userName, password } = this.state;
    console.log(userDet);
    AuthService.login(userDet).then(
      (res) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", res.data);
        AuthService.getRole(userName, password).then((res) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("role", res.data);
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("role",res.data) === "Admin") {
          console.log("Admin");
          this.props.navigate("/employees");
        }
        if (sessionStorage.getItem("role") === "User") {
          console.log("User");
          this.props.navigate("/add-employee");
        }
  })}
```

[[image: The Axios error]]
When I give the username and password,it is hitting the axios error 500

The token is generated and it is stored in the session storage but the role is not able to!

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP response of [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) means **Internal Server Error**, so the server was unsuccessful in processing your request. It could mean that there is a bug on your server-side, or it could also mean that your request is malformed. You will need to check the following in order to find out what the problem is:

- server error logs, to see what the error was
- the payload of your request, to see whether the parameters you wanted to pass were actually passed

When you see these, you will be able to determine what the source of your error probably is and following the source of the error you will probably find out what the problem is, enabling you to fix it.